# javascript popup window help

Tags: javascript

This is what I want to accomplish..I created a pop up window from my original document. this is the code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function subscribe() {
            window.open("cover.htm", "popWin", "width=125, height=240, left=10, screenX=10, top=10, screenY=10");
        }
   </script>
```

I called the function when the window loads.  Now in the the pop up I want to click on a link that will open another htm file in the original window.  I know i have to use the opener keyword but don't know how to go about doing this.

any suggestion will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be [a great article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/share_parent_childorpopup.aspx) for what you are looking to do.

Comment: Couldn't quite get that article

Answer (score 0):

You can set a function on the parent page to change the location, then use the `window.opener` to access it.

**Parent Page**

```
function changeParentURL(url) {
    document.location=url;
}
```

**Child Page**

```
window.opener.changeParentURL('http://new.htm');
```